# Redis hGet method goes to deadlock on second call when called asynchronously

Tags: node.js, redis

The issue is getMasterData when called never prints 'Passed the worst barrier' :(. God knows what I'm doing wrong. This is what I actually want to achieve.

What am I doing wrong here?
Please let me know. Any help will really be appreciated.

Below is my implementation of node redis implementation:

If I run the same this.getAll() in the loop without any await it works perfectly.

For second time await it never returns back from this.cacheStore.getByKey('organizations') and goes in deadlock forever.

No error and no response either.

Also if I remove data2 await. Still, it works fine.

```
async setKey(key, data) {
    try {
      const flatteredData = JSON.stringify(data);
      return this.cacheStore.hmset(key, key, flatteredData);
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
```

```
getByKey(key) { // eslint-disable-line consistent-return
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.cacheStore.hget(key, key, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(JSON.parse(res));
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

```
async getAll() {
    const cache = await this.cacheStore.getByKey('organizations');
    if (cache) return cache;
    const organizations = await this.db
      .collection('organizations')
      .find({})
      .toArray();
    await this.cacheStore.setKey('organizations', organizations);
    return organizations;
  }
```

```
async getMasterData(){
    const data1 = await this.getAll();
    const data2 = await this.getAll();
    console.log('Passed the worst barrier');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `setKey()` as an `async` function but when you call it in `getAll()` you forgot to `await` for it. 
Either remove the `async` or call it with `await`. I am not sure this will resolve your error but try it out!

Comment: Ah! well, thanks for that. But actually as soon as I await this.cacheStore.getByKey('organizations') (second time not first) it goes in deadlock, no error no response nothing, gone forever. It seems to be a very weird behavior.